# Pop up close with post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

im having problems with a pop up with a gridview inside.
All I want to do is when I click a button (asp.net) the pop up stay open and do the postback inside . Heres my code

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">    

        <ContentTemplate>

             <div id="conteinterAdj"align="center"  >

         <div id="contAdj" style="display:none">

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" BackColor= "#F7F6F3" text-align="center" Width="900px" BorderColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" >
        <table >
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="left">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                    Width="700px" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription2" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxControl" 
                        Width="700px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtDescription2" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="AddDoc">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                        onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="AddDoc" 
                        Width="55px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="4">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <asp:GridView ID="grdDocuments" runat="server" Width="800px" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#333333" 
                    onrowcommand="grdDocumentos_RowCommand" 
                    onrowdatabound="grdDocumentos_RowDataBound" >
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ppto" DataField="NumberItems">
                            <ItemStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocUrl">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DocDescription" HeaderText="Description" >
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmbLink" runat="server" Height="15px" 
                                    ImageUrl="~/Image/pdf.png" Width="15px" 
                                    CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 
                                    CommandName="ShowDoc" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" CommandName="deleteDoc" 
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                                   onclientclick="return confirm('You are going to remove the item. ¿are you sure?');" 
                                    ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/Eliminar.png" Width="18px" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td >
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td >
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>

            </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="439px" 
                    CssClass="lblInfo"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </div>


        </ContentTemplate>

         <Triggers>

            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button7" EventName="Click" />

        </Triggers>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here I have asyncPostBackTrigger,and when I click the button inside the updatePanel, the Pop Up disappear and the page is blocked.

Comment: Are you sure you want to accomplish this with a postback and UpdatePanel? It would be much easier to get this done with no postback and just using AJAX calls.

Comment: Yes, that would be excelent, but my knowledge in ajax is basic and I dont know where to start

Comment: You start with reading or watching tutorials. It's important to understand AJAX even if you are using UpdatePanel. Plenty of tutorials are only a web search away.